# Property in object not updating

Tags: vb.net, oop

When I use the following code to create my object, the values I assign in the with portion does no reflect in my class, and I am trying to use that values in the Sub New() portion which is in the 2nd snippet. How can I make that work?

```
Dim RoughPnl As New RoughPnl(trvPartList, pnlBasePanel, chkRoughUnderFinal.Checked) With
                 {.Material = cboMaterial.Text, .Label = cboLabel.Text, .Qty = cboQty.Text,
                  .BoardThickness = cboThickness.Text,
                  .BoardWidth = cboWidth.Text,
                  .BoardLength = cboLength.Text,
                  .BoardColor = picFinalColor.Tag,
                  .BoardImage = picFinalColor.Image,
                  .DimLinesON = chkFinalDimLines.Checked,
                  .LabelsON = chkLabelsON.Checked,
                  .SizeON = chkSizeON.Checked}
```

**2nd Snippet**

```
Public NotInheritable Class RoughPnl
    Inherits MyPanel

    Sub New(objTree As TreeView, basePnl As Panel, rpnl As boolean)
        MyBase.New(objTree, basePnl)

        'Initial values
        m_myKey = myKey
        m_refNum = refNum
        m_material = material
        m_label = label
        m_qty = qty
        m_pnlID = "Rough"
        Me.Name = m_pnlID & "key" & m_material & "-" & m_myKey
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your `With` section is run *after* the constructor completes. Therefore these variables will be their defaults when you are actually in the constructor. Is there a reason you don't just have these values provided as parameters to the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @GlorinOakenfoot, code like this:

```
Dim obj As New SomeType With {.SomeProperty = someValue}
```

Is just a shorthand for this:

```
Dim obj As New SomeType

obj.SomeProperty = someValue
```

It should be obvious why you can't use `someValue` in the constructor.  If you want to use a value in the constructor then, like for any other method, you must pas that value via a parameter.

Comment: I didn't pass them as paramenters because it seemed like extra code to write, but now looking at it, maybe its the only way. I just thought having all those are parameters looked like bad practice. How many would be too many parameters to pass? When I seen the with portion I thought it was kinda passing them, but I guess not. I'm just struggling with these objects.

Comment: A constructor, like any method, should have all the parameters that it needs and only the parameters that it needs. If you need to use a value in a constructor then that constructor must have a parameter for that value. Remember that you can overload the constructor, so you can have different combinations of parameters. If your object needs a value in order to exist then all constructors must have a parameter for that value. Any values that are optional should just be left as properties so that the caller can optionally set them.

Comment: In short, whether to add a parameter to a constructor is about need, not number. If you need a value then provide a parameter and if you don't then don't.

Comment: Ok, I apperciate the help! I will follow that advice and proceed on.